# Select2 not selecting first item as default

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am populating a drop down list in an ASP.Net page using this code

```
var xhttp

        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", "../XMLHttp/XMLHttp_GetRDRegions.aspx?RDDivision=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('ddlRDDivisions').value), false);
        xhttp.send();

        document.getElementById('ddlRDRegions').options.length = 0;
        document.getElementById('ddlRDCentres').options.length = 0;
        document.getElementById('ddlRMNames').options.length = 0;

        var ddlRDRegions = document.getElementById('ddlRDRegions');
        var element = document.createElement('option');
        element.text = '--- Please Select an item ---'
        element.value = '0'
        ddlRDRegions.options.add(element);
```

When not using Select the new element I am adding is the first selected item in the list, however when applying the Select2 in the javascript too like this.

```
$('select').select2();
```

the element is at the top of the list but is not the selected element.

I have tried creating an attribute like this

```
var att = document.createAttribute("selected");
att.value = "selected";
element.setAttribute(att)
```

which throws an error and this

```
$(element).attr("selected", "selected")
```

which does nothing.

Any and all help on where I am going wrong would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Try this way `$(element).prop('selected', true);`

Comment: where's `xhttp` onreadystate handler

Comment: @GHOST93 unfortunately that didn't work either.

Comment: @Ramanlfc that's not the relating to the question that is being asked

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: not when trying that or when adding the $(..).attr() tags, its just not selecting the item

Comment: @GHOST93 adding in console logs too it gets to it, and beyond it too

Comment: how are you selecting your element by ID or class??

Comment: @GHOST93 here the drop down list is being selected and the element added to it. `var ddlRDRegions = document.getElementById('ddlRDRegions');
        var element = document.createElement('option');` as I say without the select2 on this it works fine without having to add the jquery to ensure its selection

Comment: okay for dropdown you can try `$(...).val(yourVal)` to show the selected part. I think this will work

Comment: As I understand it select2() creates a copy of the dropdown list so anything you do to `element` after that will probably be invisible. Have you tried `$(element).prop('selected', true);` _before_ calling select2()?

Comment: @DougMcLean yea, I have tried that as per Ghost's suggestion above, but that didn't work. the select 2 is added at page load (at the end of the page) when the list in question is built the select 2 element already exists so doesn't have anything to copy, and the element it self isn't invisible as its at the top of the list, its just not selected.

Comment: @GHOST93 how \ where do you mean?

Comment: wherever you are setting the attr to selected I suggest use this `$("#ddlRDRegions").val('yourOptionValue');` instead of setting attr

Comment: @GHOST93 I am getting the same result, no error but gets to it and beyond it in the code as per my console.log output

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zm4mhwpn/

Comment: Have you included jquery to your code???? otherwise `$("#ddlRDRegions").val('yourOptionValue');` this code working fine for me you can see that in above's fiddle as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95925/discussion-between-simon-price-and-ghost93).

Comment: i have been checking its selected value when using ddlRDRegions.selectedValue and then assigning it a value, it appears it is being selected but the select2 is not showing its selected value

Comment: also, i cant get into the chat because of work policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now found the answer which was not obvious at all...

```
$(ddlRDRegions ).select2().select2('val','ddlRDRegions.selectedindex')
```

Answer (score -3):

For attr('selected', 'selected'); you need to add this to your option tag.

And for this $('#ddlRDRegions').val('0');

```js
$('#test').on('click', function(){
 $("#font_family").val('arial');
});
$('#test2').on('click', function(){
 $("#heltest").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="font_family" class="form-control" name="font_family">
<option value="0">---Select Font---</option>
<option value="tnr">Times New Roman</option>
<option id='heltest' value="helvetica">Helvetica</option>
<option value="verdana">Verdana</option>
<option value="arial">Arial</option>
</select>
<button id='test'>Click Me For Arial</button>
<button id='test2'>Click Me For Helvetica</button>
```

Comment: this would be fine but its not using the select2 element so is not a useful answer sorry

Comment: These are the ways by which you can achieve the base problem of selected attr, now you need to figure out how to use this with select2

Comment: And bdw what does this means $('select').select2(); Is that a method? And if yes then what it does?

Comment: select2 is a bootstrap control to make the presentation of things look better. `$('select').select2();` calls the jquery from select2.js  and applys the formatting to all select \ drop down lists that have `<select>` tags